# How much is original Jumanji important to the sequel?

Tags: suggested-order, jumanji-welcome-to-the-jungle, jumanji

I didn't see the original [1995 Jumanji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumanji), but was asked to watch [the sequel from 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumanji:_Welcome_to_the_Jungle).
I don't have time to watch the first one before that.

**Will I understand the sequel?** If I want to see the original in the future, **will it be significantly spoiled for me?**

In short: Is it ok to watch it in the opposite order?

Comment: By the way there is also an animated series with (I think) some characters from the original movie https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0115228/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You do not need to know anything about the original 1995 movie to understand the 2017 movie.**

The 2017 Jumanji has almost nothing to do with the original 1995 Jumanji. It is in essence a complete reboot of the franchise. There are a couple very brief references to the original, but they do not actually impact the story in any meaningful way.

The references of the original for a complete picture:

Reference #1:

> Jumanji was originally a board game which brought the world of Jumanji in to our world. You briefly get an image of the original board game in the 2017 remake.

Reference #2 (small spoiler for the first half of 1995 Jumanji):

> There is a brief mention of Alan Parrish. He was one of the main protagonists in the 1995 Jumanji, and played by Robin Williams. In the original movie, he is sucked in to the board game as a child and forced to survive in Jumanji for many years. He is eventually rescued and forced to complete the game as an adult.

Comment: It's more of a soft reboot given the two direct connections between the two films (the board game being found on the beach at the beginning of Welcome to the Jungle, and Alan Parish's hut). They clearly share continuity, making Welcome to the Jungle a soft-rebooting sequel rather than a full reboot. Other than that, your points are all correct, +1.